# PhantomJS renders different rasterized images on 2 servers with same version

Tags: qt, phantomjs, qtwebkit, qt4.8

I use PhantomJS 1.9.8 to generate PNG thumbnails from SVG documents, with a script similar to [the one provided by PhantomJS](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js). I have created a test a few months ago to check that the rendered image is the one that I expect. Today this test fails. There were probably some Debian packages that changed on the server on which these tests are done, but I didn't change the PhantomJS (which I run as a static binary) and I've read that PhantomJS is not supposed to have any external dependencies.

The two images look very similar but as I check their binary content the test just fails :

[Expected image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GC8n.png)

[Actual image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqFXL.png)

What explains this difference ? On my local environment the test still succeeds.

Comment: How do you compare the images? Please don't say that you're diffing the files. Even PhantomJS may produce different images based on the phase of the moon and whatnot.

Comment: How else would you compare images ? I do [diff the binary strings](https://gist.github.com/bperel/f8f02db7a3e9a3f60e8f) indeed, any suggestion to do that better is welcome, but I don't see why images would render differently accoring to the phase of the moon !

Comment: PhantomJS 1.9.8 uses mostly QT4.8.4 to do the rendering. I don't know whether QImage or QPainter depends on some other library which might be have updated. You really should be comparing the image data. I don't know of any libs that do this, but there are probably many examples on the web. They usually give you a percentage how much the image are similar both dependent and independent on the image sizes. This should be more robust than comparing files.